# How to get Express app config asynchronously?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, async-await

I have an Express app, developed using Serverless Framework, that will be served via AWS API Gateway and AWS Lambda. It uses Okta for authentication, and I'd like to store the various secrets in SSM. Right now I have to retrieve the secrets from SSM and store them in environment variables before I deploy the Lambda, but if possible, I'd like to retrieve them from SSM when the Lambda is invoked. Is this possible?

Here's something resembling my code (it's a work project, so I'm not at liberty to share the actual code). Note that `main` here is set as the Lambda handler.

```
import { APIGatewayProxyHandler } from 'aws-lambda'
import 'source-map-support/register'
import serverless from 'serverless-http'
import express from 'express'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import { ExpressOIDC } from '@okta/oidc-middleware'
import session from 'express-session'

const jsonParser = bodyParser.json()
const app = express()
app.engine('pug', require('pug').__express)
app.use(express.static('static'))

const oidc = new ExpressOIDC({
  issuer: process.env.ISSUER, // `https://${oktaDomain}/oauth2/default`
  client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID, // Stored in SSM
  client_secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET, // Stored in SSM
  appBaseUrl: process.env.APP_BASE_URL, // `https://${apiGatewayId}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/prod`
  scope: 'openid profile'
})

app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET!, // Stored in SSM
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: false
}))
app.use(oidc.router)

app.set('view engine', 'pug')
app.set('views', './views')

app.get('/', oidc.ensureAuthenticated(), async (_req, res) => res.render('index'))

app.get('/status/:taskId', oidc.ensureAuthenticated(), async (req, res) => { ... })

app.post('/doPost', oidc.ensureAuthenticated(), jsonParser, async (req, res) => { ... })

export const main: APIGatewayProxyHandler = serverless(
  app
) as APIGatewayProxyHandle
```

Comment: Perhaps [SSM API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/systems-manager-api.pdf)?

Comment: Well, yes, but one calls the SSM API asynchronously. That's the sticking point - how to await the SSM call before initializing the app.

Comment: Since my handler can be an asynchronous method, I'm thinking I might can do something where I await the SSM call, initialize the app, and then return `serverless(app)`. However, I need to get the thing working before I mess with that, and I haven't got it working yet. :D

Comment: If you showed the code for the SSM call that you're using, then we could show you how to call it before initializing the app.  Can't help you with code we can't see.

Comment: This might be helpful. I'd post it as the answer, but I haven't tested it. Basically I would do:

    export const main = async (event, context) => { 
        ssmConfig = await getSsmConfig(); // this would handle retrieving stuff from SSM
        const app = buildApp(ssmConfig); // build the app w/ config from ssm
        const handle = serverless(app);
        return handle(event, context);
    }

 source: https://github.com/serverless-components/express/commit/d2ed98ebc3473cc8208f6fe8bd3814e419a596de#diff-ffbd5b0f8f784045e7cd10d3aa2a936f741d6e3d1b26227c91fab7693cafbb66R43

Answer (score 0):

This *looks like* it would work, but I haven't tested it to confirm. Inspired by
[this Serverless Express PR](https://github.com/serverless-components/express/commit/d2ed98ebc3473cc8208f6fe8bd3814e419a596de#diff-ffbd5b0f8f784045e7cd10d3aa2a936f741d6e3d1b26227c91fab7693cafbb66R43)

```
import { APIGatewayProxyHandler } from 'aws-lambda'
import 'source-map-support/register'
import serverless from 'serverless-http'
import express from 'express'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import { ExpressOIDC } from '@okta/oidc-middleware'
import session from 'express-session'

const jsonParser = bodyParser.json()

// Retrieve stuff from SSM
const ssmConfig = async() => { ... }

const buildApp(ssmConfig) = (ssmConfig: Record<string, string>) => {
  const app = express()
  app.engine('pug', require('pug').__express)
  app.use(express.static('static'))

  const oidc = new ExpressOIDC({
    issuer: ssmConfig.ISSUER, // `https://${oktaDomain}/oauth2/default`
    client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID, // Stored in SSM
    client_secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET, // Stored in SSM
    appBaseUrl: process.env.APP_BASE_URL, // `https://${apiGatewayId}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/prod`
    scope: 'openid profile'
  })

  app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET!, // Stored in SSM
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false
  }))

  app.use(oidc.router)

  app.set('view engine', 'pug')
  app.set('views', './views')

  app.get('/', oidc.ensureAuthenticated(), async (_req, res) => res.render('index'))

  app.get('/status/:taskId', oidc.ensureAuthenticated(), async (req, res) => { ... })

  app.post('/doPost', oidc.ensureAuthenticated(), jsonParser, async (req, res) => { ... }) 

  return app
}

export const main: APIGatewayProxyHandler = async (event, context) => { 
    ssmConfig = await getSsmConfig(); // this would handle retrieving stuff from SSM
    const app = buildApp(ssmConfig); // build the app w/ config from ssm
    const handle = serverless(app);
    return handle(event, context); // I might need to add an "as <something or other>" to make TypeScript happy
}
```